# Set Flex component width to 100% at runtime?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml, flex4

If I am creating say a input field through `MXML`, I can set the width to `100%`. But I cannot seem to do this at runtime through ActionScript.

This works:

```
<mx:TextInput ... width="100%" />
```

This wont compile, says width is a number, not a string:

```
var textinp:TextInput = new TextInput();
someContainer.addChild(textinp);
textinp.width = "100%"
```

How can I set `100%` as the size on a component created at runtime via ActionScript?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just need to use the `percentWidth` attribute, instead of the `width` attribute.

So, the third line in your code would be :

```
textinp.percentWidth = 100;
```

This tripped me up for awhile, too.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be something simple. I promise to study the docs more carefully next time, but sometimes it's easy to miss stuff that's inherited from base UI classes.

Answer (score 10):

If you later want to switch back to pixel-based widths for the same component, here’s what you have to do:

```
textinp.percentWidth = NaN;
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is correct, but I can't comment on it coz I'm too new to SO.

When you want to add this functionality to a custom component, you can do something like this:

```
[PercentProxy("percentMultiplier")]
public function set multiplier(value:Number):void
{
  _multiplier = value;
  invalidSomethingOrDoSomething();
}

public function set percentMultiplier(value:Number):void
{
  multiplier = value / 100;
}
```

Of course, when you're doing it for width, the Container subclasses are looking for *percentWidth*, and don't inspect the metada, so don't call it *widthInPercent* or something, even though you can.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

```
var textinp:TextInput = new TextInput();
someContainer.addChild(textinp);
textinp.percentWidth = 100;
```